# Jest DOM textcontent additional whitespace

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, jestjs

I am writing test cases using Jest for a React component.
The component is a simple input box with a label of "Test Label"

When I try to get the label for a spec it returns the label with additional whitespace like so: " Test Label ", even though the DOM clearly has the content as "Test Label". I've tried using innerText but it doesn't work as I'm guessing it's not supported.

Is there a way to get the value I want - "Test Label"?

```
...
const input = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <p><label>"Test Label"</label><input/></p>
);
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(input);
expect(node.querySelector('label').textContent).toBe("Test Label")
...
```

Comment: Have you tried using the innerHTML property?

Comment: @MichaelCamden yep, it's coming back as undefined

Comment: Hmm, I would guess that something else is happening then. Testing your case locally returns the correct "Test Label" content.

    `const input = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <p><label>"Test Label"</label><input/></p>
    );
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(input);

    console.log(node.querySelector('label').innerHTML);`

...

    `Using Jest CLI v13.0.0, jasmine2, babel-jest
    Running 1 test suite..."Test Label"`


What version of Jest/Babel are you using? Is there anything else happening in the test case?

Comment: @MichaelCamden nothing else happening. Babel: 6.9.0 and Jest: 13.0.0 and Babel-Jest: 13.0.0

Comment: Silly error found it, the string was being mutated by a function call. Thanks @MichaelCamden